# Ibus icon isn't displayed correctly in Gnome-shell

Tags: gnome, ibus

I'm on Ubuntu 12.04 with Gnome 3 and I'm using Ibus to input Vietnamese.

The problem is after starting ibus, the ibus indicator vibrated for a while then the icon and its menu displayed somehow weird like the image below:

http://i48.servimg.com/u/f48/12/18/00/70/ibus10.jpg

Anyone help me please!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is caused by a flawed icon file, `/usr/share/icons/ubuntu-mono-dark/status/22/input-keyboard.svg`. You can replace the file with [this modified icon](https://launchpadlibrarian.net/112326780/input-keyboard.svg). Refer to [this bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-mono/+bug/1034872).

Answer (score 0):

You may try ibus-gjs.
ibus-gjs is supposed IBus UI in GNOME Shell environment.

The easiest way to install ibus-gjs on Ubuntu 12.04 is through the following PPA:
https://launchpad.net/~mengzhuo1203/+archive/ibus-gjs

You may try upstream version of ibus-gjs also but be warned that it is developed by a Fedora guy.